# Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Tags: sharepoint-2013, internet-explorer-11, infopath

Trying to fix this error for a customer;

They have a SharePoint 2013 intranet which has both internal and external facing urls.

When they open a form (using IE11) internally, it works fine. However, if they use the external url, it gives a critical error, with details of "Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'"

I did a quick search before, and the only things i've found are;

a) using compatibility mode

b) adding the following script to the masterpage

```
<script language="javascript">
    /* IE11 Fix for SP2010 */
    if (typeof(UserAgentInfo) != 'undefined' && !window.addEventListener) 
    {
        UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1; 
    } 
</script>
```

or

```
<script language="javascript">
    /* IE11 Fix for SP2010 */
    if (typeof UserAgentInfo.strBrowser !== 'undefined' && !window.addEventListener) 
    {
        UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1; 
    } 
</script>
```

c) Turning off enable protected mode, ensuring the site is in the trusted sites. Checking the Disable script debugging (ie) and disable script debugging (other), and unchecking the 'display a notification about every script error' options.

I've tried both iterations of the script, and neither fixed the issue - UserAgentInfo is undefined, and !window.addEventListener evaluates to false.
I also tried setting all options in c) as well - this did not work either.

Is compatibility mode really my only option here?
What could be the differences between the internal and external sites, where this occurs with one, but not the other?

Thanks in advance for any help - i'm really quite stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0):

UserAgentInfo is a function, and needs to be defined (by SharePoint) before you use it. If you check the page's source code, you should see some code like this:

```
function UserAgentInfo() {} UserAgentInfo.strBrowser = 3;UserAgentInfo.strBrowserType = 3;UserAgentInfo.intBrowserRmj = 11;
```

Your code snippet must be placed after this. Try placing your code as the very last thing before the `</body>` tag.